# How to validate the pro image field in backpack for laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack, laravel-backpack-5

I have the mutator as the example in https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-fields#image-pro

But I had trouble including the validation rules.

I tried with `'photo' => 'nullable|base64image|base64mimes:jpg|base64max:2048',`

And it works when I upload a new image, but if I have an image and try to edit another field it flags the errors:

"The photo field must be an image."

"The photo field must be a file of type: jpg."

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? or what is the correct way to validate with the pro image field?

**UPDATE**

Apparently with backpack's "image Pro" field, I get a base64 image when I select the image from my computer, so it validates fine when this happens. But when another field is edited, what is obtained from the "photo" field is, for example: "actors/photos/739503e96ef392255f6266ce3bf1dded.jpg" that is, the path where the image is saved, so the base64 validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class YourFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'pro_image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048', // Adjust the allowed file types and maximum file size as per your requirements
        ];
    }
}
```

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\YourFormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class YourController extends Controller
{
public function store(YourFormRequest $request)
{
// The request is valid, proceed with storing the data or handling the file
// The uploaded file is available via $request->file('pro_image')

```
    // Example: Storing the uploaded file
    $proImage = $request->file('pro_image');
    $proImage->store('your-directory'); // Adjust the storage path as per your requirements

    // Additional processing or database storage can be done here

    // Redirect or return a response
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work for me. Could you explain a bit what is the intention or what is the difference with creating a setter as it says here: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-fields#image-pro?

The process already works fine when a new image is loaded, the problem is when updating without loading a new image (ie keeping a previously loaded image). For example, when I modify a text field, but not the image field, I save and send a validation error on the image field, which perhaps shouldn't even validate because I'm not changing the image.

Answer (score 0):

i do this validation with custom validator extend, like this:

app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        Validator::extend('base64image',function($attribute, $value, $params, $validator) {
            $explode = explode(',', $value);
            $allow = ['png', 'jpg', 'svg'];
            $format = str_replace(
                [
                    'data:image/',
                    ';',
                    'base64',
                ],
                [
                    '', '', '',
                ],
                $explode[0]
            );

            // check file format
            if (!in_array($format, $allow)) {
                return false;
            }

            // check base64 format
            if (!preg_match('%^[a-zA-Z0-9/+]*={0,2}$%', $explode[1])) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

app/Http/Requests/XYZRequest.php

```
'photos' => 'required|base64image',
```

Is working always.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work for me.
I updated my initial question with more information.
The problem is that when loading the image it is validated in base64, but the image is NOT saved in base64, so in subsequent updates the "image" field has the path of the file and the validations show an error.
This following the steps of the backpack documentation:
https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-fields#image-pro

Answer (score 0):

you should tried to handle validation both jpg and base64 encode
I think when you select an image it will convert it to base64 encode but when you edit it, it will pick the existing path that have .jpg instead.
sorry I don't have a code.